# Proxy connection using windows authentication

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to connect to an Oracle Database using proxy authentication but with windows authentication.  I have the following connection string:

`Data Source=XXXX;Proxy User Id=PROXY;Proxy Password=PROXYPASS;User Id=MYUSER;`

This works, however MYUSER is identified externally by MYDOMAIN\MYUSER.  I need to be able to pass this in:

`Data Source=XXXX;Proxy User Id=PROXY;Proxy Password=PROXYPASS;User Id=MYDOMAIN\MYUSER;`

This results in an "Invalid Username/Password - Logon Denied" error message.

Is there any way to authenticate a user externally via this method?  Alternatively is there a way to find the oracle user from the windows credentials inside oracle?

EDIT: Please note I am using the Oracle Managed Dataaccess component

Comment: Can you not just strip off the `MYDOMAIN` bit in code?

Comment: Unfortunately there isnt always a one to one relationship between oracle and windows user name.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the registry branch `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_HOME_NAME`
string parameter  `OSAUTH_PREFIX_DOMAIN=TRUE`
On the Windows server, you must add the parameter to the registry and restart Oracle Server.

Comment: Sadly applying this key didn't make any changes, same error message.  I should have mentioned I am using the Oracle Managed Dataaccess provider.